# In below given 2 examples they are almost similar but still one's exact keyword works but others wont why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Example 1.

```
routes.js(1st file)
<ProtectedRoutes path={prop.path} component={prop.component} key={key} />

protectedRoute.js(2nd file)
        <Route
            {...rest}
            exact
            render={(props) => {
                if (verified) return <Component {...props} />;
                return (
                    <Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: routes.LICENCEKEY,
                        }}
                    />
                );
            }}
        />
```

Example 2.

```
routes.js(1st file)
<ProtectedRoutes exact path={prop.path} component={prop.component} key={key} />

protectedRoute.js(2nd file)
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(props) => {
                if (verified) return <Component {...props} />;
                return (
                    <Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: routes.LICENCEKEY,
                        }}
                    />
                );
            }}
        />
```

My question is that the first example is not working but the second example is working.
The only difference is that in 1st example I'm writing **exact** directly inside  and in 2nd example I'm passing **exact** to protectedRoute component and receiving and applying as **rest**.

Let me know if u understood my question.

**EDIT**

```
full protectedRoute.js file

import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

import routes from 'constants/routes.json';

const ProtectedRoute = ({ verified, component: Component, ...rest }) => {

    return (
        <Route
            exact
            {...rest}
            render={(props) => {
                if (verified) return <Component {...props} />;
                return (
                    <Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: routes.LICENCEKEY,
                        }}
                    />
                );
            }}
        />
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        verified: state.licencekey.verified,
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProtectedRoute);
```

Comment: Can you share the full component définition for `ProtectedRoute`?

Comment: I have edited my question and added full ProtectedRoute component file

Comment: I was more interested by the version that doesn't work. What I suspect is that you still are destructuring `exact` in `ProtectedRoutes`'s props which means it's not included in `rest`

Comment: no i have mentioned is right. 2nd example is working. It looks magic to me. That's why I asked here.  LOL

Comment: The problem is with computedMatch while passing props. It might help to anyone wants to answer. As computedMatch also have isExact property.